# c++ telegram bot. new line in sendMessage using cURL library

Tags: c++11, curl, telegram

I didn't find something helping me  in the web so i'll ask you for help.

I try sending a Message with several line breaks.

e.g.:

Hey! 
Welcome to the channel!

So my code:

```
int main(){

   CURL *handle
   handle = curl_easy_init();

   string url = "https://api.telegram.org/<bottoken>/sendMessage?chat_id-idnbr&text=Hey\nwhatsup"

   curl_easy_setopt(handle , CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());

   curl_easy_perform(handle);
}
```

Now if i set it like this i get the CURLcode 3 CURL_URL_MALFORMAT (URL not formatted right)

Any idea what to do?

Comment: Try `http://.../Line%0ABreak`. "%0A" encodes the newline in the way a URL expects non-printable characters to be encoded.

Comment: Don't know if that will work, but it might.